# How can I log a Warning to Sentry with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sentry

I would like to log very important warnings to Sentry my Flutter app. Without an Exception that does not seem possible. I don't want to throw an Exception. Sentry works fine as an exception handler and all is set up for that. Also, it would be nice to have the call stack in the warning. I have a bloc base class which would be the right place for a call like that log that warning.

Any takers ;)

Comment: Don't know if it's the correct or most elegant way to do this, but in dart you can throw any object, not just Exceptions. So maybe you can create a Warning class to catch or get the warnings and throw it to let Sentry to handle, with the difference that will be logged as a warning.

Comment: How is that different from an Exception - I could just subclass Exception or Error and call it Warning. This would still interrupt the execution flow which is my main problem.

Comment: My bad. Sorry. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since this has been cross-posted in [`flutter_sentry` repo](https://github.com/dasfoo/flutter_sentry/issues/31), here is the answer if you are using [`flutter_sentry` package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sentry): [FlutterSentry.captureException](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_sentry/latest/flutter_sentry/FlutterSentry/captureException.html)

```dart
FlutterSentry.instance.captureException(exception: Exception('Things went wrong'));
```

However, if you are using [sentry](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry) package (which is the basis for `flutter_sentry` but without tight integration with Flutter), then this looks just a little tad different via [SentryClient.capture](https://pub.dev/documentation/sentry/latest/io_client/SentryClient/capture.html):

```dart
// Assuming client is SentryClient:
client.capture(Event(...));
```

Comment: We've released a Flutter integration (Prerelease) which enables you doing that -> https://pub.dev/packages/sentry_flutter
try out and let us know if you find any issues :)